# Query Updates Wrong Entry in Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using mongoose database for one of my chat application for take history and update as per UI.

I have follow object in database.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5979dbd157634341fc8cb03a"),
"count" : 3,
"room_status" : true,
"room_id" : "s7d8a9s7d8a90sd",
"users" : [
    {
        "user_status" : true,
        "user_id" : 1501158353821
    },
    {
        "user_id" : 1501158361890,
        "user_status" : true
    },
    {
        "user_id" : 1501158369102,
        "user_status" : true
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

From request I take data `{room_id: "s7d8a9s7d8a90sd", "user_id":1501158361890 }`. As per `room_id` and `user_id` I have to update object like, `user_status : false` and `count increased by -1`.

**NOTE : If `user_status` already false than no need to decrease count by 1.**

I tried with follow query let me know furthure option.

```
room.update({
    "room_id": req.body.room_id,
    "users.user_id": req.body.user_id,
    'users.user_status': true
}, {
    '$set': {
        'users.$.user_status': false
    },
    '$inc': { count: -1 }
}, function(err, resData) {
    if (err) {

    } else {

    }
});
```

I want output like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5979dbd157634341fc8cb03a"),
"count" : 2,
"room_status" : true,
"room_id" : "s7d8a9s7d8a90sd",
"users" : [
    {
        "user_status" : true,
        "user_id" : 1501158353821
    },
    {
        "user_id" : 1501158361890,
        "user_status" : false
    },
    {
        "user_id" : 1501158369102,
        "user_status" : true
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: That should be `room.update({ "room_id": req.body.room_id, "users": { "$elemMatch": "user_id": req.body.user_id, "user_status': true } }, ....` Because without the `$elemMatch` the `"users.user_status"` can match "any" array position. You use `$elemMatch` so the "combination" of conditions is considered.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer. But Please can anyone explain differance between above query and `$elemMatch`.

```
                   room.update({
                        "room_id": req.body.room_id,
                        "users":{
                            $elemMatch : { 
                                "user_id": parseInt(req.body.user_id), 
                                "user_status" : true 
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        '$set': {
                            'users.$.user_status': false
                        },
                        '$inc': { count: -1 }
                    }, function(err, resData) {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(500).send({ status: false, message: "Error Occour to Processing Database" });
                        } else {
                            result[0]['presenter'] = false;
                            return res.status(200).send({ status: true, message: "User left Successfully", data: result[0] });
                        }
                    });
```

-
Thanks

Comment: Buy do you understand why? Or did you just read than in an existing answer?

Comment: No, Please can you explain me in Answer.

Comment: Read the comment above and look at the documentation for `$elemMatch` as well.